Updating key on all child values with yq
I have a YAML like:
foo:
   thing_1:
     key_to_update: "a"
   thing_2:
     key_to_update: "b"
   (etc)

How do I do foo[*].key_to_update = "x", effectively setting key_to_update to x for all children?

You almost had it. Drop the * as [] alone will iterate over all children:
yq '.foo[].key_to_update = "x"'

This works for both kislyuk/yq and mikefarah/yq. (See the yq info.)
